# > Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: /opt/android-sdk-linux

Tags: android, ubuntu, gradle, build, android-sdk-tools

- Ubuntu 16.04
- android-sdk at /opt/android-sdk-linux
- android home confugired (export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk-linux/")
- there is no additional tools folder in /opt/android-sdk-linux/

my gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hu.prject.sandbox.sample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

when run `./gradelew clean build` in the project folder, I got this output:

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 21.1".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 21.1" ready.
Finishing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 21.1"
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 21.1 in /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.0
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 21.1" complete.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 26".
"Install Android SDK Platform 26" ready.
Finishing "Install Android SDK Platform 26"
Installing Android SDK Platform 26 in /opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-26
"Install Android SDK Platform 26" complete.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: /opt/android-sdk-linux

IMPORTANT:
in my case no android studio, no ui, only CLI

There is android-26 folder exist with content at /opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. remove all previous android sdk files from /opt/
2. `cd /opt && wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip`
3. `unzip sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip -d android-sdk-linux`
4. `nano /etc/profile.d/android.sh`

paste this lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk-linux"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
```

5. `source /etc/profile`

check android home:

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

6. in /opt/android-sdk-linux

   `tools/bin/sdkmanager --update`

   `tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-26" "build-tools;26.0.2" "extras;google;m2repository" "extras;android;m2repository"`

   `tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses`

maybe enough at this point and the build will work...

but in my case missing some dependency, and check with

`tools/bin/sdkmanager --list`

update with the missing dependencies
`tools/bin/sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-alpha9"`

`tools/bin/sdkmanager "extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-alpha9"`

after these build success

thanks for help NinjaCoder about build tool version

Comment: You've helped me resolve my issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301455/react-native-target-with-hash-string-android-28-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Since your `compileSDKVersion` is 26, use latest version of build tools.

```
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
```