# React Native : target with hash string 'android-28' not found

Tags: android, react-native, android-sdk-tools

I've got the below problem when trying to build a React Native android app from command line. It is on Ubuntu Server so no Android Studio GUI.

I do have `android-28` installed in the folder which the error states.

`$ANDROID_HOME` is at `/home/build/android-tools`

```
build@v-ope-we-build-vm:~/Awesome/android$ ./gradlew assembleRelease --scan

> Configure project :app
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in /home/build/android-tools/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in /home/build/android-tools/build-tools/28.0.3
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 (revision: 28.0.3)" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in /home/build/android-tools/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 28 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 28 (revision: 6)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 28 (revision: 6)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 28 in /home/build/android-tools/platforms/android-28
"Install Android SDK Platform 28 (revision: 6)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 28 (revision: 6)" finished.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-28' in: /home/build/android-tools

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s

Publishing a build scan to scans.gradle.com requires accepting the Gradle Terms of Service defined at https://gradle.com/terms-of-service. Do you accept these terms? [yes, no]
yes
Gradle Terms of Service accepted.

Publishing build scan...
https://gradle.com/s/na57rru4ztmpw
```

EDIT: sdkmanager output

```
build@v-ope-we-build-vm:~/android-tools$ sdkmanager --list
Installed packages:=====================] 100% Computing updates...
  Path                 | Version | Description                    | Location
  -------              | ------- | -------                        | -------
  build-tools;28.0.3   | 28.0.3  | Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 | build-tools/28.0.3/
  platform-tools       | 28.0.2  | Android SDK Platform-Tools     | platform-tools/
  platforms;android-28 | 6       | Android SDK Platform 28        | platforms/android-28/
  sources;android-28   | 1       | Sources for Android 28         | sources/android-28/
```

Comment: Resolved by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46896341/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-26-in-opt-android-sdk-linux